# Determine for which values the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{b^{k^{2}}}{k!}$ is convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

So I am trying to figure out for which positive real numbers b this series

> $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{b^{k^{2}}}{k!}
> $$

is convergent.

Since it looks pretty hard to compare it with other series, I decided to use the ratio test.
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \left|\frac{b^{(k+1)^{2}}}{(k+1)!}\cdot{\frac{k!}{b^{k^{2}}}}\right| $$ 
$$=\lim_{k \to \infty} \left|\frac{b^{2k+1}}{k+1}\right| < 1 $$

But I am stuck here, this doesnt look too useful. Looking for some help.

Comment: As exponential kills polynomial, it must be that $\;|b|<1\;$ .

Comment: Okay , but how about my attempt to the solution? Is ratio test the way to go?

Comment: And forgot to say.. since b cant be negative, we must have that 0<b<1 ?

Comment: I'm thinking about something else now. If b=1 the inequality should also hold? What about that case?

Comment: Yes, then $\;0\le b\le1\;$ . Your attempt is fine, but one has still to deduce things. And yes: it still works with $\;b=1\;$, you're right.

Comment: Im just wondering if you could help me out with a similar exercise:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{b^{2}}\cdot{b^{k^{2}}} $$
I end up with this inequality: $$\lim_{k \to \infty} b^{2k+1} < 1 $$
So the values of b should be the same as in the previous series , namely $$ 0 \le b\ \le 1  ? $$

Comment: Well no: this time you clearly have to require $\;b<1\;$ ...

Comment: Yeah oh my bad, b cant be 1. But the rest should hold?

Comment: Observe the calculations: you can't take the limit when $\;k\to\infty\;$ *of only part of the expression*!: $$\frac{(k+1)^{b^2}b^{(k+1)^2}}{k^{b^2}b^{k^2}}=\left(\frac{k+1}k\right)^{b^2}b^{2k+1}\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}\begin{cases}0,&0\le b<1\\1,&b=1\\\infty,&b>1\end{cases}$$ So basically it is *almost* correct.

Comment: You mean that I excluded $$(\frac{k+1}{k})^{b^{2}} ? $$ The reason why I did this is because this term tends to 1 as k--> infinity. Maybe I should have been more detailed.

Comment: @fe Yes, that's what I meant....and you can't do that in the general case: it can render a wrong result. In this case it worked...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your attempt one gets that, for $|b|\le1$, as $k \to \infty$,
$$
\left| \frac{u_{k+1}}{u_k}\right|=\left|\frac{b^{2k+1}}{k+1}\right|\le \frac{|b|^{2k+1}}{k+1} \le \frac1{k+1} \to 0
$$ Then, by the ratio test the series is *convergent* for $|b|\le 1$.

One may observe that, for $|b|>1$, 
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty}\left| \frac{u_{k+1}}{u_k}\right|= \lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{|b|^{2k+1}}{k+1} =\infty
$$ and the series is *divergent* for $|b|>1$.

Comment: But since b cant be negative, I should say that 0<b<1 right? Edit: regarding the ratio test

Comment: Oh yeah.. Forgot about those cases.

Comment: Im just wondering if you could help me out with a similar exercise:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{b^{2}}\cdot{b^{k^{2}}} $$
I end up with this inequality: $$\lim_{k \to \infty} b^{2k+1} < 1 $$
So the values of b should be the same as in the previous series , namely $$ 0 \le b\ \le 1  ?$$